# I made an app from a website and I would like to How to share the current URL from the current post or page

Tags: android, android-intent

Does anybody can help me?
I have a website and I converted it using android studio into an app and I would like to implement a share button to share the current URL, not only a fixed URL.

I have the share button done, but it only shares the URL I want.  Thanks

Comment: So, what is the problem, if the button shares the URL, which you want?

Comment: @Geshode I have the same doubt as you have! This question is another level

Comment: the website is dinamyc, and i would like to share the curret dinamyc page/post, not only one URL set previously

Answer (score 0):

On button action you must capture the url
String HiUrl = webView.getUrl();

and set the string in the intent
yourIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  HiUrl ");

Answer (score 0):

```
based on your code, I found the answer:

it's not Intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Hiurl);
its share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Hiurl);
without quotes.

  if(id==R.id.mnShare)
        {
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            String Hiurl = MYWEBVIEW.getUrl();
            share.setType("text/plain");
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Site");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Hiurl);


   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "share with"));
        }
```

Comment: Am I missing something, is this an answer or part of the question? And what do you mean by "based on **your** code" as you're the op

Comment: based on dario's answer I meant